# What does "Centrality Afforded" imply?

Tags: meaning

What does "Centrality Afforded" imply? For example : we were struck by the centrality afforded to social media in general, and visual media such as memes and gifs in particular,

Comment: centrality = position in center, focus; afforded to =  given to

Comment: Note that "centrality", in this sense, is a noun.

Comment: Thank you so much Xanne and Hot Licks <3

Comment: Literally, I'd say *afforded* is closer to *made available* than to *given*.